# How to merge menu entries for normal and visual mode?

Tags: vim, menu, multiple-entries

I have many menu entries like these:

```
nnoremenu <silent> 94.015.10 &MyMenu.Test\   :call Test("%","keyw2",keyw3")<CR>
vnoremenu <silent> 94.015.10 &MyMenu.Test\   :<C-U>call Test("'<,'>","keyw2",keyw3")<CR>
```

One for normal mode '**nnoremenu**' and
One for visual mode '**vnoremenu**'

With the same keywords except the first one ("%","'<,'>")

Is there no way to merge them together?

p.e. is it possible to do this:

```
an <silent> 94.015.10 &MyMenu.Test\   :call Test("","keyw2",keyw3")<CR>
```

and check within the function if normal mode or visual mode is active?

Comment: I would like to ask why you prefer the `:menu` commands over the `:map` commands!?

Comment: @user1146332, Hi, to answer your question: with the menu command I can add it in a dropdown menu in the gui interface.

Comment: I know this, but do you really use the menu in your vim sessions!? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @user1146332, yes I do

Comment: Side note: you may want to use ranges with your function. See `:h function-range-example`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `:an`, the visual mode is automatically aborted via `<C-C>`. This means that there is no way to retrieve the mode any more (and your `<C-U>` prefix is not necessary); if you need the mode information, you have to keep the two different menu definitions.

If you would like to reduce the code duplication, you have to utilize other means, e.g. metaprogramming (that is, building and `:executing` the menu definition commands in a loop).

**Edit:** On request, here's an example of how I would tackle this to avoid the duplication:

```
for [mode, range] in [['n', '%'], ['v', "'<,'>"]]
    execute printf('%snoremenu <silent> 94.015.10 &MyMenu.Test\   :call Test(%s,"keyw2","keyw3")<CR>', mode, string(range))
endfor
```

Comment: Can you please give a short example how to do this with metaprogramming in a loop (or tell me where to read more about this)?

Comment: @Remonn: There you are. I hope this helps.